# Backing up a VM server to an external USB drive

Tags: server, usb, backup, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I have an ubuntu 10.04 server running my VMs on kvm/qemu.
I've been manually pausing my VMs (using virt-manager gui) and then copying the /var/lib/libvirt folder to an external usb drive at /mnt/usbexterno
This obviously is far from ideal.
I need a solution to run a backup everynight.

I thougt about using a cron job with a script to pause the VMs and copy the files to the drive. 
I've read on a forum that I could use virsh to save the VM state to a file, but I dont think thats what I need, since I want a full backup of everything in case the server goes boom!

So, short version. I need something to run a daily backup of my VMs to an external usb drive, the VMs can be paused during the night. Theres no GUI available on the server.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: It would be a plus if the solution could erase older backups when the usb disk gets full or has no space to run the backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me a while to get back to this, sorry to everyone that gave me tips. 
Here's the solution I ended up with.

Since I still didnt really grasp the snapshot/restore snapshot concept (yes I am kinda thick headed), I made a script to delete old files, starting from the link that [Michael K](https://askubuntu.com/users/29216/michael-k) provided, then proceeded to making a folder with todays date on the usb drive, pausing all active VMs (absolutely no need for 100% uptime here, company runs 9am-6pm),  and copying all of /var/lib/libvirt in there, and then resume VMs and be happy.

Here is the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

find /mnt/usbexterno/backup* -maxdepth 0 -type d -mtime +15 -exec rm -rf {} \;

virsh list | sed '1,2d' | cut -d' ' -f3>/tmp/vmlist

VMLIST=$(cat /tmp/vmlist)
set -- $VMLIST
for i in $VMLIST
do
    /usr/bin/virsh suspend $1
shift
done

mkdir /mnt/usbexterno/`date +backup-%Y-%m-%d`
cp -Rv /var/lib/libvirt /mnt/usbexterno/`date +backup-%Y-%m-%d`

set -- $VMLIST
for i in $VMLIST
do
    /usr/bin/virsh resume $1
shift
done
rm /tmp/vmlist
```

If anybody has any tips on how I could improve this please be my guest :D

Answer (score 1):

If your VM is named "FooVM", then you can create a snapshot using:

```
VBoxManage snapshot FooVM take FooVM_Snapshot1
```

Via command line you can configure where to store the snapshots:

```
VBoxManage configvm FooVM --snapshotfolder /media/foostick/foofolder
```

However, take care that the UBS hard drive is available all the time.

You can automate the backups using cron jobs. And there is no need to poweroff the VMs.

Comment: older backups could as well be deleted automatically: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/delete-files-older-than-x-days-on-linux/

Comment: But he is not running Virtualbox

Comment: I think I saw some similar functions while reading about virsh, I will test it and lets see :)

Comment: oops :-D       sorry - but maybe it helps someone else

Answer (score 1):

I would consider compressing the VM before sending it off but this is exactly what I have been doing.

Oh, you might want to consider saving the xml file too (`/etc/libvert/qemu/`).

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to agree, although your backup strategy is working, it may not be the best.

IMO there is not much that is necessarily unique to a Virtual Machine and there are several backup strategies available to you.

See [Ubuntu Server Guide - Backups](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/backups.html)

The backup strategy varies depending on what servers you are running. In general, on a server, I back up data (such as /var/www and databases), any configuration files I manually edit (I keep a copy of the  original file and the edited file in /root ), and a list of all installed packages (you can restore from a list of packages if needed).

As you can guess from some of my posts, I am a fan of rsync ;)